# What are the states and rewards in the reward matrix?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-chains, markov-models

This code :

```
R = ql.matrix([ [0,0,0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,100,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0,1,0],
        [1,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0,0,0] ])
```

is from :

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Artificial-Intelligence-By-Example/blob/47bed1a88db2c9577c492f950069f58353375cfe/Chapter01/MDP.py

R is defined as the "Reward matrix for each state" . What are the states and rewards in this matrix ?

```
# Reward for state 0
print('R[0,]:' , R[0,])

# Reward for state 0
print('R[1,]:' , R[1,])
```

prints :

```
R[0,]: [[0 0 0 0 1 0]]
R[1,]: [[0 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

Is `[0 0 0 0 1 0]` state0 & `[0 0 0 1 0 1]` state1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the book that uses that example, `R` represents the reward of the transitions from one current state `s` to another next state `s'`.

Specifically, `R` is associated with the following graph:

[image]

Each line in the matrix `R` represents a letter from *A* to *F*, and each column represents a letter from *A* to *F*. The `1` values represent the nodes of the graphs. I.e., `R[0,]: [[0 0 0 0 1 0]]` means that you can go from state `s=A` to next state `s'=E` and receive a reward of 1. Similarly, `R[1,]: [[0 0 0 1 0 1]]` means that you receive a reward of 1 if you go from `B` to `F` or `D`. The goal seems to be achieving and remaining in `C`, which obtains the largest reward.

Comment: thanks for sharing, can you link to an online version of the book or is this from a book copy you own ?

Comment: Since this part of the book corresponds to the first chapter, I was using the "first chapter preview" in Amazon. Not very useful in general, but enough for answering your question. Sorry!